# UINavigation's dismissViewControllerAnimated method called when closing UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've got a problem with understanding, how the iOS view controllers and alert controllers work in a specific case:

I have a custom `UINavigationController` in which there is my `UIViewController`. My Navigation controller has overridden `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` method. From this `UIViewController` I present new `UIAlertController`. Up to the point where the user clicks any button in the Alert, everything works fine. However, the strange part is, my custom UINavigationController's `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` method is being called (I don't want that, if possible...)

The Alert is presented in a regular manner (from the UIViewController within the UINavigationController):

```cxx
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"yep" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    [self takeOrder:data];
}];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"nope" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

}];

[confirmOrderAcceptAlert addAction:okAction];
[confirmOrderAcceptAlert addAction:cancelAction];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is there any option to prevent this behavior? Why does this happen in the first place?

EDIT:
The code for `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion`:

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    self.isHeroEnabled = NO;
    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
}
```

I'm using [Hero](https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero) library to animate transitions, could this be the case?

Comment: please show the code of dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion in your custom navigationcontroller

Comment: thanks for the reply, question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are subclassing UINavigationController, it is will definitely call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion.

To avoid it from disturbing the library code, check for specific ViewController Types.

Eg:

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    if(![self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]]){
            self.isHeroEnabled = NO;
    }
    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) It seems it's working. I don't get however, why this method is called. I know, "that's how it's working in ios" but whyyy? :)

Comment: Okay! Tell me why do you create a subclass in the first place? what was the requirement?  :O the answer is when you want to access a method, common to all the subclasses or set a value in the parent class which will be reflected in all the subclasses. In your case, the Hero  library maybe sets some iVar to identify a presentation viewcontroller or a popped viewcontroller(not sure of the value isHeroenabled). ;)

Comment: And the reason why it calls this method, is because the alertviewcontroller is being dismissed. The apple library will call dismissviewcontroller method, while you click on any of the alertview button , which will invoke this method of uinavigationcontroller.

Comment: Sure thing, upvoted! I subclassed the navcontroller as I needed the control over enabling/disabling the back button/swipe. Also, it's a kind of legacy code, so it was already there :) Ok, thanks for the explanation, still learning something new :)

Answer (score 0):

That's how the `UINavigationController` works

If you don't want to set that `HeroEnabled` for the actions called due to alerts. You might have to do something like

`if(![self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])  {
  self.isHeroEnabled = NO
}`